# How can I get all the bigrams within a given window size?

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn

Let's say I have this string

```
my_string = "This is an example string"
```

And I was wondering if there's a fast way to compute all the bigrams within a given "window".

For instance, if the window is two words, all the possible bigrams are

```
["This is","is This","is an","an is","an example","example an","example string","string example"]
```

But if the window if three words we have these bigrams for the first three-word window

```
["This is","is an","This an","an this",...]
```

it's easy to get bigrams using sklearn. For instance one can do

```
bigrams = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",
                  strip_accents = "ascii",
                  lowercase = True,
                  ngram_range = (2,2))

bigrams_counts = bigrams.fit_transform(my_string)
```

and will give you the list (and even the counts) of all bigrams, but it will only include the bigrams present in the string, not the other combinations (i.e. "This an" and "an this" won't be there).

So, do you know if there's a way to get all the bigrams within a given window?

Comment: Please check definition of [bigram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram). It seems to me most of the time you ask for word combinations within a window, not bigrams

Answer (score 5):

From the example:

```
["This is","is an","This an","an this",...]
```

These do not look like bigrams, but permutations of words from window. For 3 words that would be:

```
from itertools import permutations, chain
from functools import partial

my_string = "This is an example string".split()
set(chain.from_iterable(map(partial(permutations,
                                    r=2),
                            zip(my_string,
                                my_string[1:],
                                my_string[2:]))))
```

If you need the counts, use a `Counter`, but beware that overlapping will cause doubling, tripling etc. (depends on amount of overlap e.g. the size of the window) of counts for a given word pair.

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(chain.from_iterable(map(partial(combinations, r=2),
                                zip(my_string,
                                    my_string[1:],
                                    my_string[2:]))))
```

and the result:

```
Counter({('is', 'an'): 2, ('an', 'example'): 2, ('This', 'is'): 1, ('This', 'an'): 1, ('example', 'string'): 1, ('an', 'string'): 1, ('is', 'example'): 1})
```

And finally, if you need the windows as separate results, skip the chaining:

```
list(map(partial(permutations, r=2),
         zip(my_string, my_string[1:], my_string[2:])))
```

Comment: In machine learning on nlp domain, the number of times a bigram occurred in a text may have predictive power; so, why `set`? As well, how would you apply these permutations on a moving window on text, not 3 words? Will two same combinations from overlap count as different combinations or same?

Comment: Then use `Counter`. Also, these are not bigrams, since that would mean adjacent elements.

Comment: And what do you mean by "moving window on text, not 3 words"? Same combinations from overlap will count, since they are from a different window.

Comment: "Moving window" is moving window. From how the OP stated question it appears to me he wanted all 2-word combinations within a window (see his example on all 2-word combinations within 3-word window), with the intent to move that window along the whole text later.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov and `zip(my_string, my_string[1:], my_string[2:])` generates moving windows of 3 words. Perhaps you missed the split. Now the example actually looks like permutations, because "This an" and "an this" are just that (except where did that "this" even come from).

Comment: Well, I see now. `list(zip(my_string, my_string[1:], my_string[2:]))`,  it's moving, thanks!